# Is it possible to increase the "my position" marker size or replace it?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I would like to change the marker that shows my location and which direction I'm pointing to. Either resize it or use another marker like an arrow that rotates based on which direction the phone is pointing at. Looked everywhere with no luck, Is it possible?

Default:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just change the default icon, you need to add your own location manager and place/update a custom marker when your location changes

Comment: So basically on every location update I get the bearing, rotate the bitmap according to bearing and use it as a marker?

Comment: yes use the bearing and you can even use the accuracy if you also want to display a circle like the default one

Comment: Sounds bearable enough.. Thanks ;)